# Symfony RouteCollection caching - CsrfRouteBundle issue?

Tags: php, symfony

Today I have identified a bottleneck in my Symfony application. The problem is that Symfony calls `Doctrine\Common\Annotations\CachedReader::getMethodAnnotations()` over 4000 times (for every request, in production mode).

I looked at the callstack and these calls are a result of `Symfony\Component\Routing\Loader\YamlFileLoader::load()` which is called by `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Routing::getRouteCollection()`. This seems to be the core issue - it seems the RouteCollection is not cached.

After some research I found [this comment](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/7368#issuecomment-15146130) by @stof saying that RouteCollection should not be used at runtime.

The runtime usage of RouteCollection is done by the [CsrfRouteBundle](https://github.com/Genedys/csrf-route-bundle). To be precise it's used [here](https://github.com/Genedys/csrf-route-bundle/blob/a2c80f637df78aa21dcc13f6c52c42675a11b7d5/Routing/Router/CsrfRouter.php#L104) and [here](https://github.com/Genedys/csrf-route-bundle/blob/a2c80f637df78aa21dcc13f6c52c42675a11b7d5/Twig/Extension/CsrfTokenExtension.php#L53). Does this mean that the approach used by this bundle is wrong? In that case what solution do you use for CSRF in symfony?